# Checking the format of the object in Drop event

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a stack panel for which `AllowDrop` property is true and I have to drag a user control (Player.xaml) on this stack panel.
Inside the `Drop` event of Stack Panel, I have to check if the items being dragged are of the `user control (Player.xaml)` type

```
private void StackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("ProjectName.FolderName.Player"))
    {
            spHolder.Children.Clear();
            spHolder.Children.Add((UserControls.AnswerControl)e.Data.GetData("ProjectName.FolderName.Player"));
    }
}
```

If I would have been dropping a simple text on control, I would done like this:

```
private void StackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
    {
            spHolder.Children.Clear();
            spHolder.Children.Add((UserControls.AnswerControl)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat));
    }
}
```

But what I should I do when I am dropping the custom user control on the stack panel? what is the format to be specificed for this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Dictionary<Player, string> dropShapes = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Dictionary<Player, string>))
                as Dictionary<Player, string>;
```

Or

```
Player dropShape = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Player))
```